# delay between instantiating an object and void start() {}

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am following a Unity tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BrlJsdP-VGo).

The problem I am having is whenever I instantiate the shot my player gameobject is firing, there is quite a long delay (about 1 sec) before it starts moving.

Here is my code:

### Player gameobject:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player_Controller : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject bolt;
    public float fireRate;

    private Rigidbody rb;
    private int speed = 10;
    private float nextFire;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate () 
    {
        float mh = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), mv = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector3 move = new Vector3(mh, 0f, mv);
        rb.velocity = move * speed;
        rb.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(rb.position.x, -6, 6), 0f, Mathf.Clamp(rb.position.z, -4, 8));
        rb.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rb.velocity.x * -5);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("space") && Time.time > nextFire)
        {
            nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
            Instantiate(bolt, new Vector3(transform.position.x, 0, 
transform.position.z + 1.25f), transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

### Shot that is being fired:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bolt_Mover : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody rb;
    public float speed;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        rb.velocity = transform.forward * speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try using a `Debug.Log("Foo");` to see if the whole method `Start` is delayed or if it's just the speed changing that's being delayed?

Comment: On your first Update loop, "nextFire" have null value, cause it's not set it yet

Comment: @Lotan it's a float so it gets 0 by default.

Comment: @Everts you are damn right, should I delete the comment?

Comment: @r4M, I tried your script and I din't notice any delay between instantiating and moving. The only delay there is is between one and another instantiating, that is controled by the `fireRate` field... is this what you mean?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues maybe my laptops just bad?

Comment: I couldn't help you in that case...